# I deleted the user pi but it still appears in the boot screen

Tags: user

Following the suggestions to secure my raspberrypi from [this article](https://makezine.com/2017/09/07/secure-your-raspberry-pi-against-attackers/) I:

- created a new user
- changed its password
- disabled the default pi user with `sudo passwd --lock pi`
- deleted the user pi with `sudo deluser -remove-home pi`

The user pi is still available in the log-in splash screen (although the other user is selected by default). There is no `pi` folder in `/home` though. Is the pi user deleted or is it still lingering around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo deluser -remove-home pi` is not correct, and should have given an error. Long command line options such as `remove-home` usually start with two `--`. Run like this and try again:

```
sudo deluser --remove-home pi
```

(As per your comment, it seems this resolved your problem.)